# How does gcc calculate the required space for a structure?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

```
struct {
   integer a;
   struct c b;
   ...
}
```

In general how does gcc calculate the required space? Is there anyone here who has ever peeked into the internals?

Comment: There is good article on data alignment on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not "peeked at the internals", but it's pretty clear, and any sane compiler will do it exactly the same way. The process goes like:

1. Begin with size 0.
2. For each element, round size up to the next multiple of the alignment for that element, then add the size of that element.
3. Finally, round size up to the least common multiple of the alignments of all members.

Here's an example (assume `int` is 4 bytes and has 4 byte alignment):

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
};
```

1. Size is initially 0.
2. Round to alignment of `char` (1); size is still 0.
3. Add size of `char` (1); size is now 1.
4. Round to alignment of `int` (4); size is now 4.
5. Add size of `int` (4); size is now 8.
6. Round to alignment of `char` (1); size is still 8.
7. Add size of `char` (1); size is now 9.
8. Round to lcm(1,4) (4); size is now 12.

**Edit:** To address why the last step is necessary, suppose instead the size were just 9, not 12. Now declare `struct foo myfoo[2];` and consider `&myfoo[1].b`, which is 13 bytes past the beginning of `myfoo` and 9 bytes past `&myfoo[0].b`. This means it's impossible for both `myfoo[0].b` and `myfoo[1].b` to be aligned to their required alignment (4).

Comment: I have two question : 1. isn't the alignment the same for each element? 2. I can't possibly imagine the reason for the 3rd process at all..

Comment: @R___: (BTW, You might want to change your name :) ) It's up to the compiler.

Comment: Note that an empty struct, as an exception to this procedure, has size of at least 1

Comment: @R__: 1. Each type can have its own alignment requirements. In practice, the alignment requirement is almost always the same as the type for basic types. This is implementation-defined. 2. The third process is essential because you can have arrays of structures. If not for it, the second element of an array would be misaligned and thus unusable.

Comment: @bdonlan: The C language does not have empty structs. They are explicitly illegal.

Comment: For 1. what's the benefit to align `the same as the type for basic types` ? For 2. can you illustrate with another example ?

Comment: For most machines (except x86), misaligned access to types is not possible without reading a byte at a time and assembling the value manually. Attempts to perform misaligned reads will either crash or read the wrong value, and writes will either crash or corrupt memory. On x86 it's allowed (except for SSE floating point) but it's slow. Thus, for practical purposes, types must be aligned to the alignment required by the machine.

Comment: @R.., ah, perhaps I was thinking of C++ then.

Comment: @R..: I think point 2 in your algorithm is a simplification. What about packed structs?

Comment: @bitmask: Step 2 is applied recursively. If an element is an aggregate type, it has its own alignment and size. By the way, packed structs are not part of the C language (and even in compilers which offer them, they are **extremely harmful** and lead to code that breaks in mysterious ways).

Comment: IMO `align to the alignment required by the machine` is different from `align the same as the type for basic types`(alignment 1 for char,4 for int,etc)

Comment: By the way, as to why packed structs are harmful.. if I made `struct foo myfoo;` packed and took the address of `myfoo.b`, it would not be a valid `int *`. For instance, `scanf("%i", &myfoo.b);` would not be valid. It would silently work on x86 then crash horribly when somebody compiled the program on a different arch. This is because the code you pass the pointer to **cannot know** it has to access the value byte-by-byte. gcc should warn you about taking the address of packed structure members, but it doesn't.

Comment: @R__: I said it's usually the same. Some types require less alignment than their size (for instance `double` on x86 is only 4-byte-aligned in the ABI, even though it would benefit from greater alignment), but alignment for most types is the same as the size, and the alignment always evenly divides the size.

Comment: Isn't it true that `12` is also misaligned for platforms with `8` bytes alignment?

Comment: @R__: I assumed as part of my example that `int` is 4 bytes. If `int` were 8 bytes and had 8 byte alignment requirement, then I would have gotten a different result. The example must be taken in the context of particular implementation-defined parameters.

Comment: I mean this case: platform's alignment is 8 bytes, while `int` is still 4 bytes. If we want to truely meet the platform's alignment, we should align each element to 8 bytes,right?

Comment: @R__: The alignment requirement for a type cannot be larger than the size of the type.  If the platform has 32 bit `int`s that have to be aligned to 8 bytes, `int` itself must include 4 bytes of padding so that its size can be 8.  This is because both the first and second `int`s in an array of at least 2 `int`s must be correctly aligned.

Comment: @caf: You beat me to it. :-) Note that the requirement this line of reasoning imposes is that the alignment must always evenly divide the size.

Comment: @caf, let's consider the case for `char` on 8 bytes aligned platform, its pad should be 1 bytes,so 2 bytes in total,but it's still NOT aligned by 8 bytes.

Comment: @R__: I think part of your confusion might be the assumption that there's such a thing as "**the** platform's alignment". Instead, a given platform has alignment requirements for each type. For natively supported types, the alignment requirement is usually the same as the size of the type.

Comment: @R__: You're simply wrong. `char` inherently can **never** have any alignment requirement, because all sizes are in units of `char`.

Comment: Would you kindly accept the invitation to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964209/how-does-gcc-get-the-alignment-for-each-type-on-a-specific-platform

Answer (score 1):

There's not truely standardized way of aligning a struct, but the rule of thumb goes like this: The entire struct is aligned at a 4 or 8 byte boundary (depending on the platform). Within the struct, each member is aligned by its size. So the following packs with no padding:

```
char         // 1
char
char
char
short int    // 2
short int
int          // 4
```

This will have a total size of 12. However, this next one will cause padding:

```
char   // 1, + 1 bytes padding
short  // 2
int    // 4
char   // 1, + 1 byte padding
short  // 2
char   // 1
char   // 1, + 2 bytes padding
```

Now the structure takes up 16 bytes.

This is just a typical example, the details will depend on your platform. Sometimes you can tell a compiler to never add any padding -- this cause more expensive memory access (possibly introducing concurrency problems) but will save space.

To lay out aggregates as efficiently as possible, order the members by size, starting with the biggest.

Comment: A struct that only contains elements of type `char` won't have any alignment requirements (it *could* if an implementation chose to impose useless alignment, but that would be a silly implementation).

Answer (score 0):

The size of a structure is implementation defined, but it is hard to say what the size of your structure will be without more information (it is incomplete). For instance, given this `struct`:

```
struct MyStruct {
     int abc;
     int def;
     char temp;
};
```

Yields a size of 9 on my compiler. **4** bytes for `int` and **1** byte for a `char`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? On any real-world compiler this will have a size of 12.

Comment: @R: My old crappy Borland C++ Builder. That's why I said it is up to the compiler :)

Comment: The only way size could be 9 is if the implementation has no alignment requirements at all for `int`. What is the size of `struct { char abc; int def; };` ?

Comment: @R: 5 bytes. And yes, you are correct it seems. It has always been this way on this compiler. No padding and no alignment. If you change that `char` to `short`, the size is (2 bytes + 4 bytes) = 6 bytes.

Comment: In that case, it matches my answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have modified your code so that it compiles and ran it on Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler platform:

```
    struct c {
       int a;
       struct c *b;
    };

    struct c d;

    printf("\nsizeof c=%d, sizeof a=%d, sizeof b=%d",
                sizeof(d), sizeof(d.a), sizeof(d.b));

    printf("\naddrof c  =%08x", &c);
    printf("\naddrof c.a=%08x", &c.a);
    printf("\naddrof c.b=%08x", &c.b);
```

The above code fragment produced the following output:

```
   sizeof c=8, sizeof a=4, sizeof b=4
   addrof c  =0012ff38
   addrof c.a=0012ff38
   addrof c.b=0012ff3c
```

Do something like this so you can see (WITHOUT GUESSING) exactly how your compiler formats a structure.

Comment: The code in the question has a struct as a member of a struct, which is perfectly valid (as long as the inner and outer structs are of different types). Why did you change it to a pointer? And don't use `"%d"` to print a `size_t` value; either use `"%zu"` (if your implementation supports it), or use `"%d"` and cast to `int`. Finally, your code fragment doesn't produce that output; you forgot the code that prints `"addrof ..."`. (I hope you used `'%p"` and cast the arguments to `void*`.)

Comment: Code worked as written with supporting `void main()`, etc, and produced the output listed in the answer. Your comment about the inner struct is very poor.  It is common for a `struct` to have a pointer to itself which is how linked lists are built! You are probably used to `typedefs` which mask the code.  The & operator provides the `addrof` functionality.  Finally, the code was written to highlight/isolate the crux of this question.

Comment: also, re-added the printf statements for addrof lines.  Must have had a finger check!

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect (except perhaps for some embedded systems); `int main(void)` is the correct declaration. Certainly it's common for a `struct` to have a pointer to itself. It's also common for a `struct` to contain another `struct` as a member. Neither of us knows what the OP intended; if you're going to change the intent, you should at least say so. Using `"%d"` for a `sizeof` is still incorrect, and the correct format for a pointer is `"%p"` with a cast to `void*`. And why do you have the `\n`s at the beginning of the format strings rather than at the end?

Comment: And `offsetof` would show the layout more clearly than printing the addresses of the members.

Comment: It shows how the compiler lays out a particular structure. The OP was asking how the compiler determines the layout in general. And the code could be improved considerably; I'd think you'd be interested in doing that.