# Equality of structure using pragma pack in C

Tags: c, struct, structure, pragma

The reason behind the fact that the structures can't be checked for equality in C is the presence of slack bytes,which makes the comparison impossible.

But if I use #pragma pack(1) which removes the slack bytes then the comparison should be done smoothly,but it still gives error on being compared.

**Example Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma pack(1)
struct person
{
    int uid;
    char nameStart;
};
struct personDupe
{
    int uid;
    char nameStart;
};
int main()
{
    struct person var;
    struct personDupe varDupe;
    printf("\nSize of person : %3d\n",sizeof(var));
    printf("\nSize of personDupe : %3d\n",sizeof(varDupe));

    var.uid = 12;
    var.nameStart = 'a';

    varDupe.uid = 12;
    varDupe.nameStart = 'a';

    if(var == varDupe)    //Error is introduced
        printf("\nStructures are equal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Second question: Why do you have two separate types, if you believe they are equal?

Comment: @Bo Persson The second type is just for checking the logic struck in my mind about pragma pack otherwise for checking equality memcmp is helpful as suggested by Jack

Comment: @Bob Jarvis Error : D:\Code\structEquality.c|26|error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'struct person' and 'struct personDupe')|

Comment: What is a "slack byte"?

Comment: Struckt packing is implementation defined. The standard does not mention it and it does not guarantee two structs compare equal. You really should compare field-wise.

Comment: @Olaf check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300638/slack-byte-in-c-structures

Comment: @BigO: I was asking what the term "slack byte" means. I very well know about [**padding bytes**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p6) for alignment purposes in structs and padding bits in standard types. I assumed already it might be something similar; the phrase is just uncommon (never seen it before) and the term "slack" seems not to fit very well as translated by leo.org.

Comment: @Olaf btw,I got a handy resource from your reference link.

Comment: Yes, having the standard at hand is always handy.

Comment: Please do not use `#pragma pack`, it's not portable and causes all sort of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also tell the compiler how *you* detect that two values are the same

```
bool same_person(struct person* p, struct personDupe* dupe)
{ return p->uid == dupe->uid && p->nameStart == dupe->nameStart; }
```

And then you can do

```
if(same_person(&var, &varDupe))
    printf("\nStructures are equal\n");
```

Comment: That's ok,but it'll be annoying for large number of data members,It would be good if we can have some generic solution

Comment: @BigO C is not a language with reflection, a generic solution is not possible

Comment: @BigO: You can use meta-programming to generate both: the struct and a comparison function from a common description.

Comment: @Olaf can you elaborate with an example ?

Comment: @BigO: Pew, I answered questions about serialization some time ago. This is a similar problem. You might browse my answers if you can find it. Briefly, meta-programming here means to use a high-level language (I use Python forthis) to generate your C code (or part of it). You can use a HLL-construct to describe your `struct` and the HLL-code will generate the surrounding stuff for the definition and the required functions (e.g. copy, compare, whatsoever). That way you do not have to write all yourself and keep everything consistent, if you integrate it into your build-process.

Comment: @BigO: For serialization, there is [Nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~jpa/nanopb/docs/index.html), for example. I did not use it myself, but it looks quite promising. I think the caode can easily be extended for other uses.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile since you can't compare directly two `struct`.

You should use something like `memcmp`:

```
memcmp(&var, &varDupe, sizeof(var));
```

This doesn't solve the padding problem, which can be solved by ensuring that a struct is properly initialized to a known value even on padding bytes (which can be obtained by `memset` prior to initialization of fields).

But the approach of packing a `struct` to remove padding just to check if they are equal seems a fragile solution. If the compiler wants padding then it has a good reason for it, possibly performance related.

Comment: Memcmp is bit unsafe sometimes as you can have padding in struct. I think its always safe to compare member wise. But if you have forced not to do padding, then memcmp is ok.

Comment: @Ritesh: It still is not ok, as you still can have padding at the end of the struct to align the mext element if used in an array. In C the compiler cannot know.